# jQuery + hidden input fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

A simplified version of problem I am experiencing:

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/controller/action">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" class="input-text" />
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_field" value="" id="hidden_field" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_form" id="submit_form" value="Save" class="input-submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#submit_form').hover(function() {
        $('#hidden_field').attr('value') = 'abcd';
    });
});
```

And here is a really short version of the PHP backend:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

What I do is I hover the #submit_form button for a few seconds just to make sure that the jQuery code got executed, then I submit the form and:

- the $_POST['hidden_field'] is empty!

Why is that? It should contain 'abcd' as I insert it into the hidden field with jQuery on the hover event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to set the value:

```
 $('#hidden_field').val('abcd');
```

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val

Comment: it's still empty even when I use $('#hidden_field').val('abcd'); :(

Comment: @Knop, Are you sure your hover handler is being called?

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
$('#hidden_field').attr('value') = 'abcd';
```

is incorrect.  You should get an error there as you're assigning an rvalue (the jQuery object) to another rvalue (a string).  (The assignment operator needs an lvalue (e.g. a variable) on the left.)

You probably want:

```
$('#hidden_field').val('abcd');
```

or:

```
$('#hidden_field').attr('value', 'abcd');
```

(The former is more jQuery-ish, but for this case both are equivilent.)

Answer (score 1):

it is:

```
$('#hidden_field').attr('value','abcd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are hidden elements be sure to check these with something other that viewing the page source i.e. pressing F12, check with `alert()`, etc. The source of the original html page will not reflect changes made to it via javascript.